# Rails Rspec confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using rspec, and having some problems.  I'm getting the following error in rspec

```
  1) MoviesController find movies with same director should call the model method that searches for movie by director
     Failure/Error: get :samedirector, {:id => 1}
     RuntimeError:
       Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:63:in `samedirector'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my movies_controller_spec.rb

```
describe MoviesController do  
  describe 'find movies with same director' do  
    let(:movie) { Movie.create }  
    before {movie.id=1, movie.director = "Steven S", movie.title="Hello World"}  
    subject { movie }  
    it 'should call the model method that searches for movie by director' do  
      Movie.should_receive(:find).with("1")  
      #this get is passing a nil id  
      get :samedirector, {:id => movie.id}  
    end  
  end  
end
```

and this is my MovieController.rb

```
def samedirector  
    movie = Movie.find(params[:id])  
    @director = movie.director  
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated.  This is a homework problem, so if you could give me more of the intuition and point to potential lines I'm doing wrong than solution code, that would be really helpful.

**Update**

I fixed it based on what you said, and just initialized it in

```
before (:each) do
  @movie = Movie.create(:director => "Steven S", :title=>"Hello World")
end
```

However, I now have the following problem.   Seems to be it isn't recognizing that the director is Steven S in the controller.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
Movie.should_receive(:find).with("1")
```

you're changing what happens when you do `Movie.find(1)`. This replaces the orignal implementation (ie `should_receive` isn't a test spy). In particular, the return value is nil (by default). This then breaks your app code, since it's not expecting `Movie.find` to return nil

You can use `and_return` to control what value should be returned

```
Movie.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(movie)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a .id method on a nil object.

You are calling .id in two places:

```
before {movie.id=1, movie.director = "Steven S", movie.title="Hello World"}
```

and

```
get :samedirector, {:id => movie.id}
```

In at least one place, movie == nil. That is why you are getting that error. Effectively you are asking nil.id

You should not try to initialize `movie` in both `let` and `before`, as it is causing confusion. Also, local variables are not passed from the `before` clause to the `it` clause because they are different methods (therefore different local scope). Use instance variables instead.

Instead, only use the before clause, and call it @movie instead:

```
before(:each) do
  @movie = Movie.create(:id => 1, :director => "SS", :title => "hello")
end

it '...' do
  Movie.should_receive(:find).with("1") 
  get :samedirector, {:id => @movie.id}  
end
```

Be careful with the create line though. If you have attr_accessible or some such, it may not actually save all attributes, in which case you might need:

```
before(:each) do
  @movie = Movie.create
  @movie.director = "asdf"
  @movie.title = "asdf"
  @movie.save
end
```

Comment: Hi, I fixed it based on what you said, and then it brought me to an error in the next step, which I've mentioned in the update above.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: try the long form, in case you have mass assignment protection